# Accessing google calendar API with pure HTTP calls

Tags: shell, http, google-api, google-calendar-api

I was able to access the API by generating API key and using a Google web client. Now, I like to access the API using a simple HTTP client like curl **without using any client libraries supplied by Google**, I know this should be theoretically possible since those libraries have to use HTTP at their core. Has anyone done it? if so can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible! Some applications use their own backend services to make calls on Google API (without Client Lib then).
You need to get some things, like on client calls -> *clientID, authorization etc...*

Get more informations about CURL on Google here : https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/using_cURL

Concerning the OAuth 2.0 with a backend service : https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

OAuth2 or Single Sign On will allow you to access to Calendar.

Comment: Thanks Zooly, looks like Google has decommissioned ClientLogin but I found the information I was looking for in the Google OAuth Playground app itself.